# Clicking elements inside iframe with xpath but not working

Tags: python, selenium, automation

So I am trying to write a script to checkout products on the website. https://shop.telfar.net/collections/hats-belts/products/logo-belt-oxblood. I can get to the checkout filling out all of the info. I am now trying to enter values into the credit card field looking like this.
[Here is where I am trying to enter in values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PMCc.png). The element ID is "number" but it is in an iframe, I tried the switch to frame method but nothing has happened. If someone could help it would be appreciated. Here is the code I have. Thank you

```
driver.switch_to.frame(0)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="number"]').click()
```

[This is the html of the element when I inspect it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOCRl.png)

[This Is when I select the element which should be inside the iframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtZXz.png)

Comment: You are selecting the wrong frame it's (1) there's more than 1 iframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I am a bit new to selenium, so there may be redundant code. Please correct me if I can do better.

The following is my attempt to fill the form:

```
driver.switch_to.frame(1)
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="number"]')
elem.click()
elem.send_keys('1234')
elem.send_keys('1234'*3)
driver.switch_to.parent_frame()

driver.switch_to.frame(2)
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="name"]')
elem.click()
elem.send_keys('abcd efg')
driver.switch_to.parent_frame()

driver.switch_to.frame(3)
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="expiry"]')
elem.click()
elem.send_keys('01')
elem.send_keys('21')
driver.switch_to.parent_frame()

driver.switch_to.frame(4)
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="verification_value"]')
elem.click()
elem.send_keys('123')
```

Explaination:

This form **feels like** one frame, consisting of sub-frames, each holding access to one input field. This code just switches back-n-fourth between parent-frame and individual frames to access and fill the fields.

`click()` method is probably not necessary. I have kept it, just because OP has included it.

This could better be done in a loop.

Output:

[image]

Comment: Your right, Click isn't necessary. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

```
<iframe class="card-fields-iframe" frameborder="0" id="card-fields-number-6zbhoma1d5j00000-scope-shop.telfar.net" name="card-fields-number-6zbhoma1d5j00000-scope-shop.telfar.net" scrolling="no" src="https://checkout.shopifycs.com/number?identifier=6e906c187cc25b97487e744263ee3a6c&amp;location=https%3A%2F%2Fshop.telfar.net%2F8807204%2Fcheckouts%2F6e906c187cc25b97487e744263ee3a6c%3Fprevious_step%3Dshipping_method%26step%3Dpayment_method&amp;dir=ltr" title="Field container for: Card number" style="height: 45px;"></iframe>
```

You are selecting the wrong iframe.

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_class_name("card-fields-iframe"))
```